# PHP get values from 2 foreach

Tags: php

I have some problems getting values from foreach in foreach.
So I'm getting some values from database and foreach them in function, but those values have another foreach so I need to combine them.

So my response that I'm foreaching looks like:

```
"attributes": [
        {
            "id": "404954fd-38c4-4865-9e0b-41588aa6b0af",
            "attribute_id": "85dcb141-d0f6-4e89-872a-efb2dad156d9",
            "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
            "order": null,
            "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "427fa40e-53f2-4b69-84fe-a24e9d4a7411",
                    "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
                    "product_attributes_id": "404954fd-38c4-4865-9e0b-41588aa6b0af",
                    "value_id": "174eee1f-1d49-43be-b2c7-f048fa38443e",
                    "order": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": "47338db2-1523-4972-970e-bdf491860d0d",
                    "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
                    "product_attributes_id": "404954fd-38c4-4865-9e0b-41588aa6b0af",
                    "value_id": "907ce021-dc66-4d85-acfb-0a11754131d4",
                    "order": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b5a701ec-aea5-4651-a303-5206ee4dbcaa",
                    "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
                    "product_attributes_id": "404954fd-38c4-4865-9e0b-41588aa6b0af",
                    "value_id": "b3551cd3-a173-46ff-aa26-9ea294f47a65",
                    "order": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "5fc456c7-79c9-4689-ba29-ca81c8d5488c",
            "attribute_id": "ca4fca45-c8a5-496d-a054-3d9e565594a7",
            "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
            "order": null,
            "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "4718415b-05b0-4f67-bf53-1df76c4a7ee6",
                    "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
                    "product_attributes_id": "5fc456c7-79c9-4689-ba29-ca81c8d5488c",
                    "value_id": "e49efb03-f89b-4528-b4a9-e052288f112a",
                    "order": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e371f735-63df-4cbe-ad20-081fc6cfe3e9",
                    "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
                    "product_attributes_id": "5fc456c7-79c9-4689-ba29-ca81c8d5488c",
                    "value_id": "0984746e-3a7d-4767-87a0-12a2b3d0cbbf",
                    "order": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "a7f581aa-29b2-45b1-80df-3ccd9ea86755",
            "attribute_id": "f3e2ffdd-02f5-45fc-bcd5-5c732d0783bc",
            "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
            "order": null,
            "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "2658d7f7-c91a-4f8b-a565-ef6e53e820c2",
                    "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
                    "product_attributes_id": "a7f581aa-29b2-45b1-80df-3ccd9ea86755",
                    "value_id": "651f2f70-58e7-4b85-b161-045d35e00dca",
                    "order": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4d1a30b7-5daf-4c21-879c-93a917bb2778",
                    "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
                    "product_attributes_id": "a7f581aa-29b2-45b1-80df-3ccd9ea86755",
                    "value_id": "a6382c6d-87f3-416a-8400-d8ccf0385393",
                    "order": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5e7e952f-eb3b-423b-9eb3-c00daa5ca103",
                    "products_id": "eb7f0faf-7bff-45e5-bdb9-a6db1e05c4f5",
                    "product_attributes_id": "a7f581aa-29b2-45b1-80df-3ccd9ea86755",
                    "value_id": "2e47215e-5dec-4dd2-bd26-4c0b9f09d917",
                    "order": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T14:03:12.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

So to foreach them I'm doing like this:

```
foreach ($product['attributes'] as $key => $attr) {
            $attr_label =  Attributes::where('id', $attr['attribute_id'])->firstOrFail()['label'];

            foreach ($attr['values'] as $key => $value) {
                $attr_value = AttributeValue::where('id', $value['value_id'])->firstOrFail()['value'];
            }
        }
```

As you see I'm searching attribute with specific id, and after that I'm searching for values that are assigned for this attribute.
How to make it to have response out of the foreach that looks like this:

```
{
    "Size": [
        "M",
        "X",
        "XL"
    ],
    "Material": [
        "Plastic",
        "Cotton"
    ],
    "Color": [
        "Red",
        "Black",
        "Green"
    ]
}
```

I tried something like:

```
$for_attributes = array();

        foreach ($product['attributes'] as $key => $attr) {
            $for_attributes['label'] .=  Attributes::where('id', $attr['attribute_id'])->firstOrFail()['label'];

            foreach ($attr['values'] as $key => $value) {
                $for_attributes['value'] .= AttributeValue::where('id', $value['value_id'])->firstOrFail()['value'];
            }
        }

        return $for_attributes;
```

But it always says like:

> ErrorException: Undefined index: label in file

Comment: It's not clear what you expect your result to be, but it seems like you want to build a resulting array? Though I think it would be better if you tried to get exactly what you want through a single query.

Comment: What ever you are trying to do your code is overwriting `$attr_label` and `$attr_value` the whole time

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Okay So I did it like this:

```
$for_attributes = array();

        foreach ($product['attributes'] as $keys => $attr) {
            $for_attributes[$keys]['label'] =  Attributes::where('id', $attr['attribute_id'])->firstOrFail()['label'];

            foreach ($attr['values'] as $key => $value) {
                $for_attributes[$keys]['value'][] = AttributeValue::where('id', $value['value_id'])->firstOrFail()['value'];
            }
        }

        return $for_attributes;
```